# How can I get Shiny to wait a certain period of time before processing updates from UI input?

Tags: r, shiny, user-input

An application I am writing filters and summarizes data each time I apply a new filter. Because one of these filters is a search box that has a pretty large cardinality (> 10,000), and because the overall number of rows in the source data is large, which is already partially summarized, it can take a while for it to update. **I would like for there to be a buffer period where the application waits for user input to end, e.g., 1-2 seconds before actually starting the update process.**

Here's a simple example (without high cardinality), where if you toggle different options in relatively quick succession, you will see several intermediate graphs. The effect is stronger and more noticeable (and annoying) if `N` is increased. The bottleneck here is most likely the graph generation vs. the data processing, but the overall concept is the same.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Example Title'),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput(
        'yFilterCheckbox',
        label='Filter Checkbox',
        choices = c('y<=-1','-1<y<1','y>=1'),
        selected = c('y<=-1','-1<y<1','y>=1'),
      ),
      checkboxGroupInput(
        'cat1FilterCheckbox',
        label='Category 1 Filter',
        choices=LETTERS[1:4],
        selected=LETTERS[1:4]
      ),
      checkboxGroupInput(
        'cat2FilterCheckbox',
        label='Category 2 Filter',
        choices=c('BIG','SMALL'),
        selected = c('BIG','SMALL')
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('myPlot')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  library(tidyverse)
  set.seed(2021*12*21)
  N=200000
  mydata = data.frame(
    x1 = rnorm(N),
    x2 = rnorm(N),
    x3 = rnorm(N),
    c1 = sample(LETTERS[1:4], N, replace=T),
    c2 = sample(c('BIG','SMALL'), N, replace=T)
  ) %>%
    mutate(
      y1 = x1 * (1 + (c1 == 'D')) + 
       x2 * (1 - (c1 == 'C')) +
       (x3 - rnorm(N)) * (1 + 3 * (c2 == 'BIG')),
      z1 = 1 * (y1 > 0)
    )

  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(
      mydata %>%
        filter(
          c1 %in% input$cat1FilterCheckbox &
          c2 %in% input$cat2FilterCheckbox &
          case_when(
            y1 <= -1 ~ 'y<=-1' %in% input$yFilterCheckbox,
            y1 > -1 & y1 < 1 ~ '-1<y<1' %in% input$yFilterCheckbox,
            TRUE ~ 'y>=1' %in% input$yFilterCheckbox
          )
        )
      ) +
      geom_point(
        aes(x=x1,y=y1, color=c1, shape=c2)
      ) + theme_bw()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: You described "debouncing": https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.7.0/debounce.html

Answer (score 6):

You described [debouncing](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.7.0/debounce.html), where you debounce an input so that dependent components don't see rapid-fire changes.

I think you have two options:

1. Replace each `input$` that needs to be debounced with a new `reactive(input$.) %>% debounce(1000)`. This means that if a user shifts from one group to another and back, it can more easily cycle, which may not be desired.

   ```r
     yFilter_d <- reactive({
       input$yFilterCheckbox
     }) %>% debounce(1000)
     cat1Filter_d <- reactive({
       input$cat1FilterCheckbox
     }) %>% debounce(1000)
     cat2Filter_d <- reactive({
       input$cat2FilterCheckbox
     }) %>% debounce(1000)

     output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
       ggplot(
         mydata %>%
           filter(
             c1 %in% cat1Filter_d() &
             c2 %in% cat2Filter_d() &
             case_when(
               y1 <= -1 ~ 'y<=-1' %in% yFilter_d(),
               y1 > -1 & y1 < 1 ~ '-1<y<1' %in% yFilter_d(),
               TRUE ~ 'y>=1' %in% yFilter_d()
             )
           )
         ) +
         geom_point(
           aes(x=x1,y=y1, color=c1, shape=c2)
         ) + theme_bw()
       })
   ```
2. Wrap all of the inputs together into one `reactive(.) %>% debounce(1000)`, returning a named-list of groups:

   ```r
     allFilter_d <- reactive({
       list(yFilter = input$yFilterCheckbox,
            cat1Filter = input$cat1FilterCheckbox,
            cat2Filter = input$cat2FilterCheckbox)
     }) %>% debounce(1000)

     output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
       filts <- allFilter_d()
       ggplot(
         mydata %>%
           filter(
             c1 %in% filts$cat1Filter &
             c2 %in% filts$cat2Filter &
             case_when(
               y1 <= -1 ~ 'y<=-1' %in% filts$yFilter,
               y1 > -1 & y1 < 1 ~ '-1<y<1' %in% filts$yFilter,
               TRUE ~ 'y>=1' %in% filts$yFilter
             )
           )
         ) +
         geom_point(
           aes(x=x1,y=y1, color=c1, shape=c2)
         ) + theme_bw()
       })
   ```

Side note: depending on the number of inputs in your real app, you may also want to take advantage of [`bindCache`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/caching.html):

```r
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
    # ...
  }) %>% bindCache(allFilter_d())
```

Do that, and while you get the normal (now improved) delay when changing checkbox parameters, when the user revisits a previously-viewed combination of inputs, the plot presents much more quickly. (I don't know of a way to pre-cache these plots, not automatically and within the `shiny`-interface. That would certainly be nice, but not generalizable to the extent `shiny` would demand.)

Comment: Max Candocia, did anything ever come of this? No questions, no comment saying it didn't work, no accepting, nothing.